# How we get analysis services database size in azure analysis services Tabular model

Tags: azure-analysis-services

we want to know analysis services database size after it's deploy on Azure analysis services

Answer (score 3):

You can use below script to find overall size and model wise size For Azure Analysis server in (MB/GB)

```
Param($ServerName="<servername>")
$loadInfo = 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.AnalysisServices”)
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($ServerName)
if ($server.name -eq $null) {
  Write-Output (“Server ‘{0}’ not found” -f $ServerName)
break
}

$sum=0
foreach ($d in $server.Databases )
{
 Write-Output ( “Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB” -f $d.Name, 
 $d.State, ($d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString(“#,##0”) )
 $sum=$sum+$d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024
}

$SizeGB=$Sum/1024

write-host ‘Sum of Database = ‘$sum ‘ MB’
Write-host ‘Total Size of Cube Databases =’ $SizeGB ‘ GB’
```

Thanks,
Mahendar

Comment: Thanks for the script - I needed to update AMO drivers to make it work - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=asallproducts-allversions#download-the-latest 

Before I had an error message (AADSTS50011) while authenticating mentioning app id cf710c6e-dfcc-4fa8-a093-d47294e44c66. Just leaving it here in case anyone runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either this  http://www.sqlbi.com/tools/vertipaq-analyzer/ or this https://www.kasperonbi.com/new-ssas-memory-usage-report-using-power-bi/ tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSMS:

- Connect via SSMS, right click model name and properties. It will give you an estimated size of your deployed tabular model.

Use Metrics:

- Under Monitoring Tab of your Azure Server listed in Portal, goto Monitoring->Metrics->From the available list of checkboxes, check Memory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not tell the size of a given model, only the combined usage memory of all models plus memory used in processing.

Comment: Mine just errors out because the memory limit reaches.